# I have a tensor of shape [5, 2, 18, 4096]. I want to stack the 0th dimension along the 2nd dimension. How can I do it?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, transformer-model

The shape of the tensor is `[5, 2, 18, 4096]`. I want to take each tensor along 0th dimension of size `[2, 18, 4096]` and stack it on top of another tensor which is of shape from the same tensor `[2, 18, 4096]` and do it for all tensors along the 0th dimension. The final tensor should be `[2, 90, 4096]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did get to a general approach in solving this, but is there any better way to do this? Also, is it mathematically correct too?

```
chunks = torch.Tensor(self.buffer) #shape is [5, 2, 18, 4096]
chunks = chunks.permute(1, 0, 2, 3)
chunks = chunks.reshape(chunks.shape[0], chunks.shape[1]*chunks.shape[2], chunks.shape[-1]) 
#the resulting shape is [2, 90, 4096]
```

Comment: Yes, this approach yields the correct result. Note also that `chunks.transpose(0,1)` does the same thing as your permute statement and is arguably preferable since you are merely swapping axes.

Answer (score 2):

1. set up

```
a = torch.rand((5,2,18,4096)) # 5,2,18,4096
```

2. move dimensions for stacking to the top

```
a = a.permute(0,2,1,3) # 5,18,2,4096
```

3. stack first 2 dimensions

```
a = torch.vstack(list(a)) # 90,2,4096
```

4. permute

```
a = a.permute(1,0,2) # 2,90,4096
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out there's a very simple approach: `torch.hstack` always stacks along the second dimension (i.e. along axis 1). For instance, consider the following:

```
start = torch.arange(120).reshape([5,4,3,2])
result = torch.hstack(list(start))
```

The tensor `start` has shape 5,4,3,2, but `result` has shape (4,15,2), which comes from stacking 5 (4,3,2) arrays along axis 1.

Applying `list` to a multidimensional tensor breaks the tensor up along the main axis. In this case, `list(start)` is a list containing 5 (4,3,2)-shaped tensors.